Express session cookie not getting sent to the front end if I am setting secure=true in expression session
I am trying to set a cookie to store session using express-session.
I am sending requests over HTTPS.
app.use(session({
    secret: env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: true, // Ensure secure is set to true for HTTPS
        sameSite: 'none', // Required for cross-origin cookies
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 hour         
    },
    rolling: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING
    })
}));

If I only put:
cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 hour         
    },

Then the cookie is received at the browser but it is not working because it is coming from https and cross origin. If I put:
cookie: {
        secure: true, // Ensure secure is set to true for HTTPS
        sameSite: 'none', // Required for cross-origin cookies
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 hour         
    },

Then the cookie is not received at the front end at all. I have deployed frontend and backend both at Vercel.
I tried to put secure: true, sameSite: 'none', in the cookie but then the cookie is not received at the frontend at all.

To understand the question, please clarify - In the post title secure is written true, the same in the third code is false : secure: false, is there any typo here ? Additional point to clarify is that Is this sent over http or https?

I have updated the question. And yes, it is being sent over https.

To debug the issue, please try rolling false.

I did rolling: false. But it is still not sending the cookie. When I am setting secure: true, the server is not sending cookie, otherwise it is sending.

rolling to false was requested for testing based on the documentation https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html. Please see the sub sections rolling and uninitialized in it. The summary is rolling:true uninitialized:false will not send cookies.  Quoted text -  "Note When this option is set to true but the saveUninitialized option is set to false, the cookie will not be set on a response with an uninitialized session. This option only modifies the behavior when an existing session was loaded for the request."

Adding to my previous comment, please check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862094/express-js-node-js-browsers-are-not-setting-cookie-when-secure-true-samesite?rq=2 It mainly has two points: sameSite:none and app.set('trust proxy', 1); Please see if it applies to your case.

Adding to the comment above, please note this point as well: to be clear, the browser is not rejecting the cookies. Instead the cookies are stored in the name of the 3rd party domain name from which the response is sent. It is also included in the same post.

Is the issue still persisting?

Yes, the issue has been fixed. I added proxy: true in the session and it is working now.

Thank you for the update. It would help others if you update this solution as answer to the post.

Will do. Thanks!

The issue has been resolved by setting proxy trusted.
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy

Mohit Sharma has confirmed the same in his comments.
Citation:

Express JS/ Node JS : Browsers are not setting cookie when secure=true, sameSite: 'none'

express-session



For Development:
cookie: {
  httpOnly: true  
}

For Production:
cookie:{
   http:false,
  secure: true  

}

If a cookie is set with the secure flag, it will only be sent to the server by the browser over https, and not plain http. This should for production environments.
However, when developing an app, you will use plain http. If you set your session cookie as secure in this case (using plain http), the server will never receive it, and you will experience a new empty session on each request.
So in short, you should only set the cookie as secure if you are using https and httpOnly if you are using http.
